# Получить указатель на структуру из C в C#

Tags: c#, c, указатели, struct

Здравствуйте. Можно ли в C# получить указатель на структуру написанной на C? Если можно, то как?

Comment: получить то можете. Тупо функцией типо `int func(Struct a){return (int)(&a);}` А что дальше с ним делать будете?

Comment: А зачем вам? Какая ваша настоящая задача?

Comment: Да мне с ней нечего не нужно делать. Я вызываю функцию из dll написанной на C. И вот она требует в аргументах свою же структуру из библиотеке. Вот я и хотел получить указатель на эту структуру и передать этот указатель в функцию.

Comment: может есть смысл написать свою обёртку над вызовом на C?

Comment: А можно подробнее про обёртку? Дело в том, что я с неуправляемым кодом раньше дело не имел.

Comment: [Статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114953/) старая, но может быть будет полезна.

Comment: @Mr.Evgen: Ну так передавайте её через `IntPtr`. Это официальный тип-обёртка над указателем.

Comment: @Mr.Evgen: Покажите код, в котором вы получаете адрес, и код, куда вы его передаёте.